# Prove $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is antisymmetric iff...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove that $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is antisymmetric iff $ \forall v\in\mathbb R^n:\langle v,Av\rangle=0 $

$\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is just the dot product.

I'm a little stumped by this problem. I'm fairly sure that the $\Leftarrow$ part of the proof can be proven by a judicious choice of vectors $v$.  For example, we can show that the diagonals of a matrix that follows this property are zero since $\langle \vec e_j,A \vec e_j \rangle=0$, where $\vec e_j = (0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0)^T$ is the $j^{th}$ standard basis vector of $\mathbb R^n$.  I still need to show, however, that the "diagonally opposite" entries add to zero.

Not sure where to start with $\Rightarrow$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\Rightarrow$: If $A$ is antisymmetric, then $A = -A^T$ and so $$(v,Av) = v^T Av = -v^T A^T v = -(Av,v) = -(v,Av),$$ so $(v,Av) = 0.$

$\Leftarrow$: Your way seems to work. Also consider the vectors $v = e_i + e_j$; since you know that the diagonals vanish, you are left with $A_{ij} = -A_{ji}$ by the fact that $(v,Av) = 0.$

Comment: Thanks for the quick and concise answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given that
$$
\langle u,v \rangle = \langle u_ie_i,v_je_j \rangle = \langle e_i,e_j \rangle u_iv_j = g_{ij}u_iv_j
$$
where $g_{ij}=\langle e_i,e_j \rangle$ is the symmetric matrix of the dot product.

Then
$$
\langle v,Av \rangle = g_{ij}v_i(A_{jk}v_k)=(g_{ij}A_{jk})v_iv_k
$$
We have that $gA=0\iff A$ is antisymmetric.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your notation.  What is $g_{ij}$ supposed to be here?  What is the "symmetric matrix of the dot product"?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: see the edited answer