# Quadratic forms of two matrices are equal then the matrices are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A,B\in M_n$, then prove that if $x^HAx=x^HBx$ for all $x\in C^n$, then $A=B$

Comment: The quadratic forms are functions, so they're equal iff they have the same value at each point of $C^n.$ What values do you get for $x = (x_1, \ldots , x_n)$ with $x_i = x_j = 1$ and $x_l = 0$ for all $l\ne i,j $?

Comment: Then we can get $(A_{ii}+A_{ij}+A_{ji}+A_{jj})=(B_{ii}+B_{ij}+B_{ji}+B_{jj})$

Comment: I think I know how to prove it. First, we pick $x$ with $x_i=1$ and others are $0$, so we have $A_{ii}=B_{ii}$ for all $i$. Then we pick $x_i=1,x_j=1$, then we have $A_{ii}+A_{ij}+A_{ji}+A_{jj}=B_{ii}+B_{ij}+B_{ji}+B_{jj}$, ie, $A_{ij}+A_{ji}=B_{ij}+B_{ji}$. Finally, we pick  $x_i=1,x_j=i$, then we have $A_{ii}+iA_{ij}-A_{ji}+iA_{jj}=B_{ii}+iB_{ij}-iB_{ji}+B_{jj}$, ie, $A_{ij}-A_{ji}=B_{ij}-B_{ji}$. Then we have $A_{ij}=B_{ij}$.

Comment: @Falang your notation is a bit strange towards the end there, but you seem to have the right idea.

Comment: If A is symmetric then we have: $2xAy = xAx + yAy - (x+y)A(x+y)$. Then we can pick off entries of $A$ by taking $e_iAe_j$. If $A$ is not symmetric I don't think it's correct.

Comment: @Nate We don't know whether it is symmetric. Did you mean you don't think the claim is right or Tim's idea is right?

Comment: The claim is incorrect unless you assume that $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian.  As a counterexample, let $A$ and $B$ be any anti-Hermitian matrices. We note that $x^HAx=x^HBx=0$ for any $x\in\mathbb C^n$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Could you please explain why $x^{H}Ax=0$ in this case.

Comment: @user84413 [I sure can.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422809/prove-a-in-mathbb-rn-times-n-is-antisymmetric-iff) I can also clarify something if you find that explanation insufficient.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for your reply.  The only part I'm confused about is changing the order in the inner product in the complex case.  (I'm probably doing something wrong, but I was getting $\bar{z}=z^{H}=x^{H}A^{H}x=-x^{H}Ax=-z$ for $z=x^{H}Ax$.)

Comment: @user84413 I made a mistake there. We actually have $$\begin{align} x^HAx&=\overline{(Ax)^Hx}\\&=\overline{x^HA^Hx}\\&=-\overline{x^HAx}\end{align}$$ So that for all $x:x^HAx$ is purely imaginary. The equality I had holds only under the restriction that $x\in\mathbb R^n$ and $A$ has real entries

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you for checking this for me. (I'm very rusty on this material, so I wasn't sure about this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yet another proof.  I assume $A$ and $B$ are hermitian and $x$ is complex. The idea is to prove that hermitian matrix $T=A-B$ has all zero eigenvalues and thus $T=0$ which readily implies $A=B$.
\begin{align}
\lambda_{min}(T)=\min_{x\in C^n,~||x||_2=1}x^H(A-B)x ~~~~~~~~~~~ \lambda_{max}(T)=\max_{x\in C^n,~~||x||_2=1}x^H(A-B)x
\end{align}
This follows from so called rayleigh ritz ratio. Now $x^HAx=x^HBx$ implies that $x^H(A-B)x=0$ for all $x$. Thus $\lambda_{min}(T)$ and $\lambda_{max}(T)$ are both zeros. Thus your required proof.

Answer (score 3):

So that this question can finally be resolved, a formal answer:

First of all, this statement **is true**, though it does not hold in its restriction to real-valued matrices and vectors.  We have the following proof, as partially constructed by Falang:

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with complex entries.  Let 
$$
e_i=\pmatrix{0&\cdots&0&1&0&\cdots&0}^T 
$$
Be the $i^{th}$ standard basis vector of $\mathbb C^n$ for $1\leq i\leq n$.  We note that when $x=e_i:$
$$
x^HAx=A_{ii}
$$
When $x=e_i+e_j$ for $i\neq j$, we have
$$
x^HAx=A_{ii}+A_{ij}+A_{ji}+A_{jj}
$$
And when $x=e_i+ie_j$ for $i\neq j$, we have
$$
x^HAx=A_{ii}+i(A_{ij}-A_{ji})-A_{jj}
$$
Now, suppose that $B$ is a matrix such that $x^HAx=x^HBx$ for all $x\in\mathbb C^n$. Setting the above products equal for each matrix, we have for all $i:$
$$
A_{ii}=B_{ii}
$$
which is to say that the matrices must share all diagonal entries, and for all $i,j:$
$$
\cases{
A_{ii}+A_{ij}+A_{ji}+A_{jj}=B_{ii}+B_{ij}+B_{ji}+B_{jj}\\
A_{ii}+i(A_{ij}-A_{ji})-A_{jj}=B_{ii}+i(B_{ij}-B_{ji})-B_{jj}\\
}\implies\\
\cases{
A_{ij}+A_{ji}=B_{ij}+B_{ji}\\
A_{ij}-A_{ji}=B_{ij}-B_{ji}\\
}\implies\\
\cases{
A_{ij}=B_{ij}\\
A_{ji}=B_{ji}\\
}
$$
Which is to say that all non-diagonal entries are equal. Thus, any two matrices $A,B$ such that $x^HAx=x^HBx$ must have identical entries and must therefore be the equal.

Comment: How can the statement be true, but not true for real-valued matrices?

Comment: @StefanSmith See my explanation in the comments above. We can find two different real matrices $A,B$ so that $x^HAx=x^HBx$ whenever $x$ is a real vector (in particular, you can choose $A$ and $B$ to be antisymmetric). However, with the right choice of $x\in\mathbb C^n$, you find that $x^HAx\neq x^HBx$

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you were restricting $\mathbf{x}$ to be real, I was thinking of $\mathbf{x}$ as a ''vector'' rather than a ''matrix''.